# Host and virtual machine cant ping each other

Tags: vmware, vmware-player

My hosts is Win 10, virtual machine is ubuntu on VMware play. 
I fixed the VMnet1 IP as 192.168.32.1 and set static address 192.168.32.10 in /etc/network/interfaces on Ubuntu.
But I can't ping each other successfully. 
Who can tell me the reason in detail? 
Thanks in advance.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Or5Bg.png)

Answer (score 0):

You should do next:
1. Check if Virtual machine's network use bridge mode (not NAT)
2. Use the seme network and subnet on Win10 net interface and Ubuntu (look at screen please http://prntscr.com/9u5b38)

Answer (score 0):

at first sight there is not a problem.
you can provide for dhcp to assign ip address automatically for ubuntu and then you can restart network service.